# dumpe2fs not finding any superblock

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have a HD in pretty bad shape. I'm prepared to accept is dead but I'd like to recover the data from it.

Running badblocks on it gives a HUGE list of numbers.

Trying to run fsck.ext4 on it just says:

```
fsck.ext4: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdd1
```

So I guess the first superblock is fried.

I'm trying to use a backup super block so I'm trying to determine where it is with dumpe2fs but I just get:

```
$ sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdd
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
dumpe2fs: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdd1
```

I guess everything is reading my HD as being empty, isn't it?

Is there any way to recover it?

Is there any way to *guess* the location of a superblock backup?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Doesn't "short read" indicate a physical error with the hard drive.    A short read might be expected with a pipe or network but not a locally attached block device.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the command `dumpe2fs /dev/sdd` sent an error, there is an other way to obtain the location of a superblock backup :

```
mkfs.ext4 -n /dev/sdd
```

From the `man mkfs.ext4`

`-n` Causes  mke2fs  to  not  actually create a filesystem, but display what it would do if it were to create a filesystem.  This can be used to determine the location of the backup superblocks for a particular
              filesystem, so long as the mke2fs parameters that were passed when the filesystem was originally created are used again.

Then, you just have to repair your partition using the superblock:

```
fsck -b 98304 /dev/sdd
```

replace `98304` by your superblock's number.

Comment: I got a valid superblock and I'm fscking now. Everything points to, not only a great answer but also a solution for (some of the) data on my HD. Thanks. I'll wait for the process to end before accepting but it seems great.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to help when I can.

Comment: It worked awesomely. I've recovered most of my data. Thanks

Comment: It didnt work for me , Please can u provide another solution . I tried with all the backup superblocks . (I have done dd if=/dev/mmcop1 of=/dev/zera ) So whole data is wipedout from disk , (Lost all the backups) . i have also tried testdisk .

Comment: If u can anser my question . It is most likely u have answered https://superuser.com/questions/1281168/completely-delete-and-make-again-superblock-on-usb-ext4-partition

Answer (score 0):

Your hard drive appears to have many physical errors, as you reported by badblocks and mention that fsck is saying a "short read" error occurred.

I recommend running `ddrescue` on it and copy the filesystem image to another device before attempting any filesystem repair.  ddrescue can take a very long time to finish if there is a lot of damage (even more than 24h in some cases)

Trying to write to a badly physically damaged drive will most likely result in creating more errors and damaging more data.