# Grub fail under Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-10, boot-repair

Problem was pretty nasty, because I could not start my Ubuntu 14.04 system. Grub multiboot was functioning well for year. I did not do anything that should cause problems, only using windows 10 system and also Ubuntu before fail of GRUB. After that only windows 10 could boot . In answer section I show my possible solution but I just want to ask, if you know what was source of the fail of starting GRUB.

log before repair (I do not know what it means):
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23507441/

log after repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23508013/

Comment: You mean you have [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time) ?

Comment: Well, if I understand your link correctly, I would say no. I did not have a "superblock error and drop to busybox". (What is busybox?). I simply could boot windows 10 only, no GRUB menu was visible after that error. Of course I have other version of Ubuntu, maybe it is not important

Comment: Grub cannot boot fast start up or hibernated Windows. And Windows updates may turn it back on. Boot-Repair says you have fast start or hibernation on. You still should be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, often f10 or f12 check you manual. Turn off fast start up. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: @oldfred Sorry, but I do not know what you mean. Maybe it is due to my poor knowledge. I could boot Windows, but I could not boot Ubuntu.

Comment: @oldfred I do not see "fast start or hibernation on". But if "UEFI boot menu" is multiboot for my notebook (=Boot Manager), blue norton style menu. I has now 3 options: 2 ubuntu and 1 windows. First ubuntu goes straight to GRUB. Second ubuntu goes: ubuntu boot failed [OK]. After that again goes to GRUB (probably due to restart). And windows menu turn off the computer (to my surprise).

Answer (score 0):

I respond for this question: What to do to start damaged GRUB. As I am pretty newbie I just googled and it worked well. My notebook is Lenovo G50.

1) get functioning live linux system. (in my case Ubuntu 14.04 live on USB)

I think this is proper help in English:
(https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

2) then using Boot-repair utility. (totally new for me)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

which was quite straightforward to install and launch.

3) I have NO guarantee it will work.

4) Both system start from GRUB. But in menu there is more choices than it used to be. (Recovery modes which I do not know).