# Why fallback to initframs in ubuntu 17.04 after dual booting from windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, 17.04, fsck, initramfs

I dual boot my ubuntu with windows 10. and this days everytime i reboot my pc to ubuntu after using my windows 10, it fall backs to initramfs. and i have to fsck my /dev/sda6 to correct and reboot .. then go back to ubuntu . Is windows causing ubuntu partition to get corrupted in some way or what?

everytime it says /dev/sda6 was not correctly unmounted

I am frustrated doing fsck /dev/sda6 [sda6 my ubuntu partition] everytime after i restart from my windows 10.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 uses a feature called "fastboot" while "shutting down", so that the next time you start, windows will boot up faster. This causes the ntfs partitions to be locked while shutting down. And if you have set ntfs partitions to auto-mount in fstab, you get thrown into initramfs.

There are 2 workarounds.

1. Disable this fastboot feature in windows 10. This will slow down the boot process of windows though. Read more about the reason to be disabled [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting).
2. If you don't want to disable fastboot, then the following works for me. Get into windows from grub and "restart" in the login prompt. Then proceed into Ubuntu. I have restart in quotes because you need to use the restart button instead of shutting down and booting up. Restarting windows 10 doesn't use fastboot and hence the ntfs partitions are not locked.

Comment: i think this is my issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time

Comment: still trying to figure out

Answer (score 0):

Remove ext2fsd from windows. Done. somehow ext2fsd from windows was messing up with the latest ext4 linux partition. So when i removed ext2fsd from windows, i have never faced similar problem. ext2fsd has most likely to do something with superblock change or something.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember, my permanent fix was to do e2fsck -b -y /dev/sda6 32768.
It just spits out a ton of numbers for ~10-30 minutes and kicks me back to a prompt. When I rebooted, it booted fine.

Comment: yes i do the same everytime. but doing this on everyboot after i boot back from windows 10 is frustrating. something is def going wrong.

Comment: After some research I found that e2fsck, the command I sent, modifies superblocks, while fsck doesn't. You should try what I sent just to see if the outcome is any different. Also, the finished line should say clean. Try what I sent and see if it does anything different than what you've been doing.

Comment: Wow, don't recommend someone to write superblocks without knowing anything about his partinioning... that sounds like a really bad idea.