# Filesystem corruption on shutdown/reboot

Tags: mount, hard-drive, filesystem, shutdown, ext4

I have a system which dual boots between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10. This system contains an SSD (both OSes are there)  a couple of internal disks, one of which is formatted in NTFS and the other one in EXT4 and an external disk, formatted in NTFS. Most of the time I use linux.

Mountpoints for all the disks except for the EXT4 disk have been created automatically by ubuntu, since they were all present when I installed ubuntu. The EXT4 disk was added later, and I manually created a mountpoint and fstab entry, pointing to a subdirectory under my home directory (i.e. orestis/newdisk).

The issue is that most of the time when I reboot or shutdown the system, the filesystem becomes corrupted, with invalid superblock and inode counts. The damage does not appear to be permanent, since an fsck restores everything to working order, but it is annoying and time consuming.

I have been using pycharm and python virtual environments with this disk, but I have tried to make sure that everything is closed and even issue unmount manually, to no avail. The thing is that I've had no similar issue with other disks. The disk is new and has been checked thoroughly for hardware errors

Answer (score 1):

Well, it would appear that the cause of the issue was the existence of the ext2fsd driver (and possibly another similar windows driver I had been toying with). Although I don't remember having booted windows each time this issue occured. Uninstalling the ext2 drivers seems to have resolved the issue for now.

See:
[How can I prevent Windows 10 from corrupting the ext4 superblock every time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/849872/how-can-i-prevent-windows-10-from-corrupting-the-ext4-superblock-every-time)