# Ubunt 18.04 & Windows 10 dual boot File corruption on boot/shutdown

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, filesystem, windows-10

So I've set up a desktop with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (kernel version: 4.15.0-60-generic) for about a month and a half ago. The desktop contains both SSD & HDD, and when installing Ubuntu I divided the root partition `/` to half of the SSD, and `/home` partition to half of the HDD. (The computer had W10 before, and the partition space were allocated through W10) The computer also contains a Nvidia GTX1080 Graphic card.

About two weeks ago, the Ubuntu boot crashed and didn't get past booting phase and went in to rescue mode. I've managed to boot it by removing file corruption `fsck -y /dev/sdb2` in recovery mode (`/dev/sdb2` is my HDD partition).

Since then, every time I reboot/shutdown my computer properly, The file system gets corrupt. It's either one of the two cases: 1. on reboot it just crashes, and can be booted with the same step as above (`fsck` in rescue mode). 2. first reboot work, but upon Ubuntu login some files are corrupted. Notably files I've modified/created in the last session.

The file corruption seems to be isolated to the HDD only, and have so far not affected the SSD. I'm not sure if the problem is hardware related, if I did some partitioning wrong, or if the dual boot (W10) is causing the problem.

I've so far done the following:

- Extended test with [Smartmontools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) on `/dev/sdb`, with result "Completed without error"
- Removed WSL from Windows 10, and checked for ext2fsd in W10 for uninstalling (Based on the solution from this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089121/filesystem-corruption-on-shutdown-reboot) and [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) )
- Removed the Windows partition in HDD from W10 (SSD partition is enough for my use)
- Checked the output of `journalctl -b` after each boot. The following error did occur on all of them (but not all of them seems to be related):

`kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Could not install PciConfig handler for Root Bridge PCI0 (20170831/evrgnini-245)`

`kernel: Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e`

`kernel: [drm:intel_bios_init [i915]] *ERROR* Unexpected child device config size 39 (expected 38 for VBT version 221)`

`gdm3[1565]: GLib: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed`

Any tips or where I should start looking is appreciated! (and If additional info or terminal output is needed, I'll add it asap)

Edit: also tested updating Nvidia driver, since some users had file corruption related to the Graphic card driver. But the problem still persist.

Edit2: Installed GParted and removed one small Windows partition on the HDD that wasn't visible from the partition tool on Windows.