# How to recover data from an ext4 partition mounted incorrectly?

Tags: partitioning, mount, data-recovery

I was in the process of rsyncing data from /mnt/disk1 to /mnt/disk2 and had already modified fstab to remount /mnt/disk1 as /tmp. I didn't pay attention to the progress of the rsync and during the process some parts arrived for the system so I shut it down to install them. I know this is my own stupid fault, in 15 years I've never lost data like this so I'm venturing down a new trail.

**Is there any way to recover the data in it's *original* structure and names?** A total of 64K was written to the disk while mounted as /tmp. I'm running PhotoRec right now but the recovered data is not very usable (recup_dir.32/f03183747.txt as an example)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any recovery software available for ext4?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41601/is-there-any-recovery-software-available-for-ext4)

Comment: I'm not looking for recovery software in general. I can recover the data, what I'm looking for is software that will recover the names and directory structure as well.

Comment: Answer adapted as per your comment.  **0:-)**

Comment: I edited the title to add more information.

Comment: TeskDisk helped me a couple of days back. It is a bit hard to figure out. But in the end, it gave the drive as it is.

Comment: @user227495 I tried out TestDisk but since the partition had been mounted and written to (only 64K) it didn't solve my problem. I only guess that it was due to being mounted and written to, I may have not been using it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Do not write to `disk1` any more: use it for reading only.**
2. If you need to do writes, make a copy first using `ddrescue` and write to the copy only.

   ```
   apt install gddrescue
   man ddrescue
   ```
3. If `disk1` contains an `ntfs` file system, use [RecuperaBit](https://github.com/Lazza/RecuperaBit) first!
   As `ntfs` contains multiple MFTs, you *might* recover *some or all* of the directory structure.
4. If you arrive at this step, you probably have EXT2/3/4 FS on your disk.  Recovering the directory structure is going to be difficult if both superblocks are overwritten: try [this first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/796240/how-to-restore-my-superblocks) *on the copy you made from the original disk.*
5. Use [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) before you use PhotoRec
6. Use [autopsy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/autopsy) before you use PhotoRec
7. Use [R-Disk](https://www.r-studio.com/free-linux-recovery/) before using PhotoRec
8. Only if all else fails, start using [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

*The best solution here is to restore your backup thought* and if you don't have a backup, **[start making a backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) ASAHP**

Comment: It's ext4 - wish it was zfs or it was in a raid :(

Comment: RAID is not a replacement for a backup: it just replicates the same mistake over multiple drives.

Comment: true, I was thinking along the lines of gluster. Anyway none of the software you mentioned was able to do what I needed. In the end I just recreated the files that I absolutely had to have and will keep the image I created around if I notice something else missing. Since you supplied an answer that, while didn't solve my problem, did provide something like PhotoRec to recover some data (all others failed).

Comment: Sorry to hear that, thanks for the acceptance, favour returned: question upvoted!