# How to recover from missing partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

my issue comes from a co-worker who has somehow corrupted an important 7TB hard drive. I believe they filled the space on the disk to 100% over the weekend and somehow messed up the partition information, but I can’t know for sure.

Anyhow, I’m in a pickle. Where once there was a partition like:
/dev/sdc1

Now the partition is gone (though the sdc disk is still present). I need the data on that disk, but I’m not sure how to proceed. fschk failed, mount fails (though without any error message which is weird), and the operating system is behaving weirdly because apparently user account information was on that disk.

I have other computers available for use, but I was really hoping someone could give guidance on how to recover files on the hard disk (or ideally restore the part job without totally erasing the data on the disk).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. There's not enough info to offer anything beyond vague suggestions. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the file system on `sdc1` (2) what process may have filled the disk to capacity (custom software, logs, streaming data, etc.). With this, it may be possible to offer some preliminary ways forward.

Comment: Does the output of the mount command indicate anything for that device, since there was no error?

Comment: If the data is important to your business, then don't let amateurs muck around and possibly make things worse. Take the hardware to a professional data recovery service and get an estimate. This is also a valuable lesson about backups. If you do want to muck around and try amateur data recovery, then start by researching the subject. Data recovery is far too broad and complex of subject to be easily answered here.

Comment: Does testdisk or parted rescue show the missing partition? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1157315/how-to-recover-data-from-an-ext4-partition-mounted-incorrectly & [testdisk or parted rescue restore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/654386/windows-10-upgrade-lead-into-grub-rescue/655080#655080) & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/944371/grub-and-ubuntu-disappeared-after-windows-update

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You need to contact a data recovery service.